# How to calculate the Resolution According to some specific resolution?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-ndk

In My Application i have One button like this :

[image]

The Resolution of that button is 192x32. And when i put this button in to drawable-mdpi, it seems good to layout. Now for other screen resolution for multiple screen support which size of button i have to make to see the Good Layout Design according to other Devices screen ?
I mean for drawable-ldpi and drawable-hdpi, which resolution i have to make for this button ? How to do Such calculation for to make this button size to fit for all the screen size ?
Please help me for this.
Thanks.

Comment: best is to provide 9-patch image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to create multiple buttons for multiple screen support.
Instead create a single button and set the width and height at run time.This is achieved by getting the display width and height. Use the bellow code to get the display H & W values.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

based in the above values set the button width and height at runtime.

Example:

```
Button bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
bt.setWidth(width);//screen width(fill_parent)
bt.setHeight(height/6);//1/6 of the screen height
```

The above code set the button width to screen(display) width size and height to 1/6 of the screen.

Comment: So for respect to MyButton resolution, which height and width i have to set for Multiple screen size support. As i am using wrap_content for height and width in xml file.

Comment: And you have set only height as height/6 per the Screen display, but what about width ? should i have not set width as width/6 ??

Comment: give any values. If you use the above code,it will automatically adjust the button width and height based on the display value.

Comment: The above code i set the button width to screen width(fill_parent)

Comment: Ok. So for everyScreen Size support i have to set the height as height/6 ?? And What about width?  should i have not set the width as width/6 ?

Comment: That means your code set the Button width as screen width. And if i want to set the some specific width then i have to set the width as pen requirement, am i right ???

Comment: ok. Thanks. Right now i am going to solve it by putting different images for different screen Size. but if i got any problem in layout i will defenatly follow your answer. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

There is much information on this subject on the [android developers website](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). In particular, there is a list of the various dpi levels and what range of DPIs that they correspond to.

Also, Rather than providing different images for different resolutions, you could make the image a [nine-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch), and have it auto-magically expand to fit the button. Although if you want to keep the highlighting in the background proportional, it might be somewhat difficult to make it expand vertically.

Comment: Ohh ! So According to Document of the nice-patch if i Put the One Image of Button with the .9.png formate then it will be autometicaly set the size with respect to different resolution of the device screen ??? Or should i have to put it into different res directory like drawable-ldpi,hdpi or mdpi ??

Comment: I have read the Developer's Multiple Screen Support documentation but there they provide the whole screen Size for all multiple device. Instead of it i want to set my button for Multiple Screen size Resolution So thats why i need help.

Comment: reply me for My comment please.